# Mapbox : How to change MGLFillStyleLayer "fill-outline-width"

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

Can I know is there any option to change the `MGLFillStyleLayer` "fill outline width” to custom width,

```
 let fillStyleLayer = MGLFillStyleLayer(identifier: identifier, source: source)

 fillStyleLayer.sourceLayerIdentifier = identifier

 fillStyleLayer.fillColor = MGLStyleConstantValue<UIColor>(rawValue: .red)
 fillStyleLayer.fillOpacity = MGLStyleConstantValue<NSNumber>(rawValue: 0.2)
 fillStyleLayer.fillOutlineColor = MGLStyleConstantValue<UIColor>(rawValue: .red)
 fillStyleLayer.predicate = predicate
 fillStyleLayer.isVisible = true
 self.mapView.style?.addLayer(fillStyleLayer)
```

Like this,

```
 fillStyleLayer.fillOutlineWidth = MGLStyleConstantValue<NSNumber>(rawValue: 5)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It currently is not possible to adjust the outline/stroke width for a `MGLFillStyleLayer`. Relevant changes to the style spec are being discussed here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4087

Depending on your use case, one workaround is to create a `MGLLineStyleLayer` from the same source and style the `lineWidth` on that line. You can then add the line layer above the fill layer. This may not be ideal if you have multiple individual `MGLFillStyleLayer` objects, as this can impact performance.

```
let fillStyleLayer = MGLFillStyleLayer(identifier: identifier, source: 
...
self.mapView.style?.addLayer(fillStyleLayer)

let fillLineLayer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "line-layer", source: source)
fillLineLayer.lineWidth = MGLStyleConstantValue<NSNumber>(rawValue: 5)
mapView.style?.addLayer(fillLineLayer)
```

Comment: Hi @jmkiley, i know this will workaround, but the problem is i need to create two layers with different identifiers, also while removing need to remove both. Thanks for your reply.